# Incremental id based on another column's value

Tags: pandas

From this DataFrame:

```
car_id    month
93829     September
27483     April
48372     October
93829     December
93829     March
48372     February
27483     March
```

How to add a third column which is basically a new `id` for `car`, but an incremental one, like this:

```
car_id    month        new_incremental_car_id
93829     September    0
27483     April        1
48372     October      2
93829     December     0
93829     March        0
48372     February     2
27483     March        1
```

Currently I'm doing it by using `groupby('car_id')` to create a new DataFrame, to which I add an incremental column, which I then join back to the original DataFrame using `car_id` join key.

Is there a less cumbersome, more direct method to achieve this goal?

---

**EDIT**

The code I'm currently using:

```
cars_id = pd.DataFrame(list(car_sales.groupby('car_id')['car_id'].groups))
cars_id['car_short_id'] = cars_id.index
cars_id.set_index(0, inplace=True)
car_sales.join(cars_id, on='car_id', how='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
In [49]: df['new_incremental_car_id'] = pd.factorize(df.car_id)[0].astype(np.uint16)

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
   car_id      month  new_incremental_car_id
0   93829  September                       0
1   27483      April                       1
2   48372    October                       2
3   93829   December                       0
4   93829      March                       0
5   48372   February                       2
6   27483      March                       1

In [51]: df.dtypes
Out[51]:
car_id                     int64
month                     object
new_incremental_car_id    uint16
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from `pd.factorize` you can

Use, `map` a dict constructed from unique values.

```
In [959]: df.car_id.map({x: i for i, x in enumerate(df.car_id.unique())})
Out[959]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    2
6    1
Name: car_id, dtype: int64
```

Or, using `category` type and `codes` but not in the same order.

```
In [954]: df.car_id.astype('category').cat.codes
Out[954]:
0    2
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    0
dtype: int8
```

Comment: Provided that the `car_id` column is already of type `category`, then using `car_id.cat.codes` can be from 20 to 200 times faster than using `pd.factorize` (the larger the DataFrame the higher the speed gains)